# How to insert array data with one query to unique field of database?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, insert-update, laravel-5.6

I have sample working code for add array of data to database:

**Migration:**

```
Schema::create('words', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('word')->unique();
    $table->integer('type')->default(0);
    $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Code:**

```
$words = [
    ['word' => 'apple',   'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['word' => 'peach',   'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['word' => 'banana',  'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1]
];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    Word::updateOrCreate($word);
}
```

In my database words will be unique and for unique inserting I use [updateOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate) method. In my code have **3 queries** to database. How I can insert unique array of data to database with **one query**? I seen to [updateOrInsert()](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert) but with it also I can't insert words to database with one query.

Comment: Have you tried ```Word::insert($data);```?

Comment: Yes! But it return error. Because my `word` field on databse have `unique` attribute. See to my migration code. But it can insert array of data with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't out of the box, because Eloquent does not support `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY` constructs.

You will probably need something like [this package provides](https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key).

This will work for your usecase, but I'm not a big fan of the static approach it uses.

Also keep in mind that this produces MySQL queries and (like using `DB::table('x')`) it's not using Eloquent, so it will not set/update timestamps on the model, there are no events triggered, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the below code.

```
DB::table('words')->insert([
            ['word' => 'apple',   'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1],
            ['word' => 'peach',   'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1],
            ['word' => 'banana',  'type' => 1, 'is_active' => 1],
        ]);
```

Comment: Here duplicate words will be inserted or on duplicate value return error am I right? @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: @Otabek Yes, an error will be generated when the user adds duplicate value., But my answer is multiple record insert in a single query.

Comment: Can I without errors add unique words to database with one query?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do it with one raw db query using [insert-on-duplicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Not tested, but perhaps something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO words (word, type, is_active) VALUES ';

foreach($words as $row) {
    $sql .= '('.$row['word'].','.$row['type'].','.$row['is_active'].') ';
}

$sql .= 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE word = VALUES(word)';

DB::statement($sql);
```

You also may want to put your timestamps in there as well.